# Unable to use cd in .prog

Tags: oracle, shell

while executing the following .prog script No such file or directory is thrown

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
  param1="$5"
  echo "Parameter1 : $param1"
  l_outgoing="outgoing"
  l_out_path="$INTERFACE_HOME/$l_outgoing"
  echo "$l_out_path"
  cd $l_out_path
```

The script works fine till  `echo "$l_out_path"` and it gives out the correct directory

Comment: Is `$INTERFACE_HOME` an absolute path? If not what is the current directory when the script is running? Does the script file itself have `\r\n` line endings so the path has a trailing carriage return? You failed to quote the variable on the `cd` line: does the path contain whitespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Script was made in Windows and migrated to Unix Sever.

using the command dos2unix worked!!

No other changes was done